# Best way to implement an (inclusive) filter in C

Tags: c, algorithm

The scenario is the following: I have a big list of events I need to parse and only let pass the ones I need. What would be the best way to achieve this? My code so far looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i, j;
    char events[4][15]; /* for the sake of the test only*/
    char *ptr;

    /* probably loaded from a config file */
    const char *filter[] = {"first_event", "third_event"};

    /* just preparing data so far */    
    strcpy(events[0], "first_event");
    strcpy(events[1], "second_event");
    strcpy(events[2], "third_event");
    strcpy(events[3], "foo");

    /* my approach is to have two iterations */
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (strcmp(filter[j], events[i]) == 0) {
                printf("pass -> %s\n", events[i]);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the sizes of `n` (number of items) and `m` (number of values to accept on), but that is `O(n*m)` .. which is "quite bad". If `m` is fixed/bounded then it's `m*O(n)`, which might be acceptable. Other approaches might be to look for the item using a `O(lg m)` (i.e. a binary search) or `O(1)` (i.e. a hash) which reduce the bounds to `O(n log m)` and `O(n)`, respectively. Of course, for small values of `n*m`, it generally doesn't matter ..

Comment: Why do not you use 'grep' or 'awk', if you are with Linux?

Comment: @pst Which aspect of a hash table are you describing as O(1)? Worst case constant memory use for representation? Best case constant time for in-order traversal? If your're going to bring analysis into this discussion, at least be specific about that which you're analysing...

Comment: @pst Before inserting or fetching to a hash table, a hash must be calculated. Calculation of the hash is based upon the length of a key. Does this seem like an O(1) operation in terms of worst case analysis of constant time? If it is, then perhaps a PATRICIA trie can insert and fetch in O(1) worst case constant time, too.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue "to look for the item", time complexity. The hash does not need to be the length of the key either to uphold the hash/equality relation - and, in most cases the hash/compare functions (for a single item) themselves are taken to be constant time (i.e. there is a bounded length), which is what I chose to do here. If you wish to further analyze/correct my comment, consider an answer as it will be more useful/visible.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Also, only the fetch/check complexity is of importance if discounting the insertion/building of the structure (which is another omission in my original comment).

Comment: @pst You're still not being specific, and the same omissions can apply to other data structures such as trees. After finding the correct position to insert to, insertion is O(1). So what? Perhaps, you might want to consider reading a book about constant time analysis, thoroughly and repeatedly until the differences between the three types of constant time analysis sink in. I'm over and out...

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Why does insertion matter? Also, what are the "three types of constant time analysis"? Just some keywords so I can track it down would be nice - do you mean Time/Space/Amortized or is this the wrong track?

Comment: @pst insertion only matters if we're talking about insertion. Otherwise, the same points are valid for retrieval, too. You can't exclude the hashing algorithm from consideration if you're not prepared to exclude the algorithm used to find the correct position in a tree. Best, average (there are multiple of those, too) and worst case are three constant time complexities.

Comment: @sheng: this is an example, the real code is inside an event daemon...

Answer (score 2):

You can not use stl `map` in C, otherwise it would be the easiest way to achieve `m*log(n)` overall complexity where m=number of events and n=maximum length of all filters. Now next easiest way to achieve `m*log(n)` would be using a [Trie tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). You will find a ready to use trie tree implementation [Here](http://c-algorithms.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=c-algorithms/c-algorithms;a=tree;f=src;hb=c-algorithms-1.2.0).
A possible use of that implementation may look like this (I did not try compile it):

```
Trie *ttree = trie_new();

for(i=0; i<numberOfFilter; i++) {
    trie_insert(ttree, filter[i], (void *) 1); //insert your filters in the tree
}

for (i=0; i<numberOfEvents; i++) {
    if (trie_lookup(ttree, events[i]) != TRIE_NULL ) { //check whether i'th event matches with any of the filters
        printf("pass -> %s\n", events[i]);
    }
}

trie_free(ttree);
```

Comment: That trie isn't m log(n) in worst case constant time. It's a rather slow log(n), because it involves passing through nodes that don't have values attached. This can be avoided by using a PATRICIA trie, instead.

Comment: Well, compress trie is necessary to reduce the memory use (by reducing total number of pointer to address next node), it do not reduce the complexity of search. So I do not get what you mean by "slow log(n)".

Comment: @sowrov, this is interesting, will try it out, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

"The best" isn't very well defined. If you have a large number of items, you'll see significant performance increases by using standard C's *qsort* and *bsearch*, with minimal complications or changes to your code necessary. That's *pretty neat*, but I don't know if it fits your definition of *best*. For a definition of "the best" that this code is excluded from, see this answers comments:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i, j;
    char events[4][15]; /* for the sake of the test only*/
    char *ptr;
    Size_t item_count = 0;

    /* probably loaded from a config file */
    const char *filter[] = {"first_event", "third_event"};

    /* just preparing data so far */    
    strcpy(events[item_count++], "first_event");
    strcpy(events[item_count++], "second_event");
    strcpy(events[item_count++], "third_event");
    strcpy(events[item_count++], "foo");

    qsort(events, item_count, sizeof *events, strcmp);

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        char *pass = bsearch(filter[j], events, item_count, sizeof *events, strcmp);
        If (pass != NULL) {
            printf("pass -> %s\n", pass);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets say, events array contain "first_event" multiple times, then the output of the OP's code will print "first_event" multiple times, but you code will print only once :-?

Comment: @Sowrov Ah, how the definition for "the best" can vary... Thanks for bringing that up! I was struggling to think of definitions that would contradict my own.